# Database monitoring - Item not supported

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

I created an item for monitoring a value from a database table but it's "Not supported" without any further explanation, and I can't find any relevant documentation. A "getting started" guide on the various issues would have made `Zabbix` so, so much friendlier.

Here's my configuration:

Item name: RESPONSE_TIME

Type: Database monitor

Key: db.odbc.select[response_time]

Username:

Password:

SQL Query: select RESPONSE_TIME from dbname.monitor_data order by action_timestamp desc limit 1;

Type of information: Numeric unsigned (the value is a MySql INT)

Interval: 50

Store value: as is

Show value: as is

New Application:

Applications: none

Populate host inventory field: none

Description: Monitors the response time for the latest action on dbname.monitor_data.

The database was created on the MySql that comes with the Zabbix server installation. So it's sitting on the same host machine.

There is no zabbix agent on the machine. The OS is Ubuntu 12.04.

I installed ODBC but I'm not sure if it's configured correctly or not.

Like I said, the item is "Not supported."

What am I missing?

EDIT: One problem was that my `ODBC` wasn't installed correctly. It is installed now and tested to work through `isql`: `sudo /usr/local/bin/isql -v eyalora`

I changed the Item key to `db.odbc.select["response_time",eyalora]` which seems to be the correct syntax, and now I'm getting the following error: `Cannot connect to ODBC DSN:[SQL_ERROR]:[01000][0][[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/lib' : file not found]|`

Is this a `ODBC` issue or a `Zabbix` issue? Do I have a permissions problem? 
What's the next step? Do I need to relogin or something like that?

Comment: Zabbix 2.4.5: Configuration → Hosts → Items of the frontend, when rolling the mouse over the error icon, you may expect to see more specific messages about why an item went unsuported. What is there?

Comment: Invalid number of parameters. I'm guessing it's in the key? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, according to https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/config/items/itemtypes/odbc_checks db.odbc.select[] item should have two parameters.

Comment: So I need to install ODBC, right? Can you recommend a reasonable way to do it on Ubuntu? I tried the Zabbix manual here, https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/odbc_checks but I run into a "No package unixODBC-devel available" when I try installing it with yum, and I also tried downloading the connector from MySql's site but their instructions is even more obscure.

Comment: @JanGaraj, any chance you could look at my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31382128/im002unixodbcdriver-managerdata-source-name-not-found-and-no-default-driv It's about my failed attempt to get ODBC to install correctly. This is becoming a real nightmare.

Comment: @JanGaraj I installed odbc correctly - and edited the question with the details. But the Item is still not supported and the reason is still Invalid number of parameters.

Comment: @Eddy switch to zabbix user and test your scripts as zabbix user, probably permission problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that `Zabbix` was looking for `odbc.ini` and `odbcinst.ini` in `/etc/` while `isql` was looking for it in `/usr/local/etc`.

I was modifying the copies in `/usr/local/etc` and once I realized that `zabbix` only sees it in `/etc/` it started working.

The best solution is probably to link these two copies so that you only have to modify one location.

For completion here's my `odbc.ini`:

```
[dsnname]
Description = MySQL connection to dbname database
Driver  = MySQL
Database = oraaudit
Server = localhost
UserName = ****
Password = ****
Port  = 3306
```

And the `odbcinst.ini`:

```
[MySQL]
Description = ODBC for MySQL
Driver = /usr/lib/odbc/libmyodbc.so
Setup = /usr/lib/odbc/libodbcmyS.so
FileUsage = 1
```

Comment: I know this is old as heck but can you please explain me how do you know where Zabbix is looking for ODBC files?
I can connect to my database using `isql MYDSN` in terminal, but Zabbix doesn't finds MYDSN.