# [IM002][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified

Tags: ubuntu, odbc, ubuntu-12.04, zabbix

I'm trying to install `ODBC` on `Ubuntu 12.04` for the purpose of using it with `Zabbix`. I installed `unixODBC` as per these [Zabbix instructions](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/odbc_checks) and modified my /etc/odbc.ini to look like this:

```
[eyatest]
Description           = MySQL connection to 'dbname' database
Driver                = MySQL
Database              = dbname
Server                = localhost
UserName              = root
Password              = ****
Port                  = 3306
Socket                = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

But when I try connecting with `isql` I get the error in the title of this question:

```
sudo isql -v eyatest

[IM002][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified
```

What am I missing?

EDIT: My `/etc/odbcinst.ini` looks like this:

```
[MySQL]
Description = ODBC for MySQL
Driver = /usr/lib/odbc/libmyodbc.so
Setup = /usr/lib/odbc/libodbcmyS.so
FileUsage = 1
```

When I do `odbcinst -j` I get the following:

```
unixODBC 2.2.14
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /home/eyal/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```